# use laravel Eloquent's updateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i want  to insert a new record if doesn't exist and update it if exists, i came across a method updateOrCreate, but im having hard time implementing it

```
$list =   mList::updateOrCreate(
      [
        ['user_id' => 162, 'movie_id' => 862] 
      ],
        [ 'tag' => 'watched'] //this data should be updated if the above got match
 );
```

but im getting the following query exception

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '162' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `lists` where (`162` = 862) limit 1)

it should look for a column called user_id not 162

ps: im doing this with two conditions where(user_id = 162 and movie_id =862)
but when i do it with a single condition it works surprisingly.
if there is any other eloquent method can do the same please refer to me ..

Comment: Why are you wrapping the attributes array with an array? Should this: `[ ['user_id' => 162, 'movie_id' => 862] ]` be like this: `['user_id' => 162, 'movie_id' => 862]`?

Comment: @Doom5 thanks maan it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[ ]` insead of `[ [ ] ]`, like:

```
$list = mList::updateOrCreate([
    'user_id' => 162, 
    'movie_id' => 862
], [
    'tag' => 'watched'
]);
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of how the above solves the problem. This will help others in understanding the issue. See also [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: explanation: first argument is [ ] not [[ ]]